# Swift: Overloaded == operator being used on another type

Tags: ios, swift, operator-overloading

I have overloaded the "==" operator for a class called `PBExcuse`, but when trying to compare `EKSourceType` objects the compiler tries to use my `PBExcuse` overloaded operator and won't compile. The error message is: "'EKSourceType' is not convertible to 'PBExcuse'".

Here is the applicable code:
Where Comparing:

```
for (var i = 0; i < eventStore.sources().count; i++) {
        let source:EKSource = eventStore.sources()[i] as EKSource
        let currentSourceType:EKSourceType = source.sourceType
        let sourceTypeLocal:EKSourceType = EKSourceTypeLocal
        if (currentSourceType == sourceTypeLocal){ //something is wrong here!!
            calendar.source = source;
            println("calendar.source \(calendar.source)")
            break;
        }
}
```

In PBExcuse.swift:

```
func == (left:PBExcuse, right:PBExcuse) -> Bool{
    if (left.event == right.event && left.title == right.title && left.message == right.message){
       return true
    }
    return false
}

final class PBExcuse:NSObject, NSCoding, Equatable, Hashable{...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EKSourceType` is a struct

```
struct EKSourceType {
    init(_ value: UInt32)
    var value: UInt32
}
```

so you can only compare its `value` property:

```
if (currentSourceType.value == sourceTypeLocal.value) { ... }
```

The compiler message is misleading. Since `==` is not defined for `EKSourceType`,
the compiler tries to convert the struct to *some* other type for which `==` is defined.
Without your custom `PBExcuse` class, the error message would be

```
'EKSourceType' is not convertible to 'MirrorDisposition'
```

Note that you can simplify the loop slightly to

```
for source in eventStore.sources() as [EKSource] {
    if source.sourceType.value == EKSourceTypeLocal.value {
        // ...
    }
}
```